# Hot water in cold water pipe

Tags: bathroom

I recently had a recirculating pump installed in the far end of my system. (The master bathroom is at the far end of the house away from the water heater.) There are two outside faucets that are apparently tied into the cold water line. When I now turn the water on outside to water grass or plants, hot water comes out of the cold water tap as well as the hot water tap in the master bath without the recirculating pump coming on.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What's your question?

Comment: This sounds like an "old work" recirculation pump that is installed between the existing hot and cold lines without a dedicated return. What type of recirculating pump is it, does it include some type of shutoff valve to stop hot water from passing to the cold side, and are the cold water pipes getting hot even when the pump is turned off?

Comment: Need more details before an answer is appropriate.  You should also direct your complaint to whoever installed this, unless you have a question here first.  You've got a backflow issue it seems.